# How to Flat Nested JSON using Nifi without Using JOLT

Tags: json, apache-nifi

Is there any Processor which can flatten , Nested Json Using Nifi.

I have tried using FattenJson Processor.But its not giving Expected Record.

[image]

Input :

```json
{
  "header": {
    "messageId": "111"
  },
  "security": {
    "Identifier": "123~NCA~FCAD",
    "businessDate": "2022-03-07",
    "UIIdentifier": [
      {
        "sourceCode": "NA"
      },
      {
        "sourceCode": "NA-NA"
      }
    ],
    "Classification": [
      {
        "sourceCode": "aaa",
        "ClassificationCode": "ObjectType"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Output :

```json
{
  "header.messageId": "111",
  "security.Identifier": "123~NCA~FCAD",
  "security.businessDate": "2022-03-07",
  "security.UIIdentifier": [
    {
      "sourceCode": "NA",
      "sedol1Identifier": null
    },
    {
      "sourceCode": "NA-NA"
    }
  ],
  "security.Classification": [
    {
      "sourceCode": "aaa",
      "ClassificationCode": "ObjectType"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected OutPut like below:

```
"header.messageId": "111",
"security.Identifier": "123~NCA~FCAD",
"security.businessDate": "2022-03-07",
"security.UIIdentifier.sourceCode": "NA",
"security.UIIdentifier.sedol1Identifier": {},
"security.Classification.sourceCode": "aaa"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the flattenJSON processor, which could be an option. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.16.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FlattenJson/